# Why does my "Stack Apps" account appear twice in my list of accounts?

Tags: support, profile-page

I was just looking at my list of accounts and was puzzled to see that Stack Apps appears twice. No other site appears twice. When I hover, the user number in the link is the same for both lines. This happens whether I click Accounts while on my Meta profile or my SO profile. In fact, it even happens on my Stack Apps profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the accounts tab on your profile, there's a button to clear the associations.  Do that, and then re-associate your accounts.  That should clean things up.

Comment: Well that was reasonably terrifying, though only for a moment. However, I still have two lines for Stack Apps.

Comment: @KateGregory, give the cache a few minutes to catch up.

Comment: You're right, it's good now. Any idea why this happens?